# maven installations on ubuntu fails

Tags: maven, ubuntu, package, apt-get

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on VMPlayer 6.0.4 here on ubuntu when I am trying to install maven i am getting the following errors.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install maven
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 maven : Depends: libaether-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libplexus-containers1.5-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libsisu-ioc-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwagon2-java (>= 2.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

As I am new to Linux I am not understanding why its failing and how to solve this.
After googling I tried

```
i)apt-get update (success) 
ii)apt-get upgrade (failed as below)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic oxideqt-codecs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

but still same issue 
It would be helpful if someone suggestion me how to fix and install maven 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be too late to answer, but I had same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS --  so this may be helpful

Here is a work around...

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libwagon2-java_2.2-3+nmu1_all.deb
```

The command above will install: `libwagon2-java_2.2-3+nmu1_all.deb`

After this you will be able to install Maven by: `$ sudo apt-get install maven`

Answer (score 0):

Update your packages by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then try to install.